# MultiTeXt Component in CQ5

Tags: adobe, aem

I am new to Adobe Cq5 Development.I want to Create a component for a Footer of a webpage

Sample is given below

Phones

SmartPhones

4gPhones

2gPhones

Featured Phones

The Footer Component should accept List of Text and should go to Childpages when a particular text is selected.For eg.When
SmartPhones text is selected,SmartPhone Page (ChildPage) has to be dispalyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wordings a bit odd but I think you want a list of links. A tutorial of how to create a custom xtype that can store both a link and its text can be found at: http://cq.shishank.info/2011/12/19/multifield-with-custom-xtype/

Once you've got that its a matter of creating a simple component that iterates over the stored multifield and creates list items.

Comment: Thanks Chris.Will Try this and Let you know